# How to append lat/lng in react-google-maps to this.state.markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I've implemented in this:

```
 populateLocations() {
    var arrOfAdds = [],
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder()

    this.props.properties.map(function(property, i) {
      if (geocoder) {
        geocoder.geocode({
          'address': property.street
        }, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
             // debugger
             arrOfAdds.push({
               position: {
                 lat: results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                 lng: results[0].geometry.location.lng(),
               },
               key: i,
               defaultAnimation: 2,
             })
            }
        });
      }
    }, this)

   arrOfAdds.map(function(add, i) {
     this.state.markers.push(add)
   })

    console.log('arrOfAdds', arrOfAdds)
    console.log('this.state.markers', this.state.markers)
  }
```

I'm trying to basically update this.state.markers (an array which has all my lat/lngs where the pins will be dropped) with whatever is in the arrOfAdds array, but I suppose I can't update this.state.markers? 
It seems like when i run a debugger in the function, it skips over the `this.props.properties.map(...` and goes straight to the `arrOfAdds.map...`, which from the beginning is an empty array, doesn't append anything and then goes through the `this.props.properties.map(...` to create a properly populated arrOfAdds.

Fairly confused as to how to do this, would love assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

geocoder.geocode is most probably an async function, so it means your addition code is run *before* you received the actual data. If you move that code inside the geocode callback it is probably fixed (you could simply do `this.state.markers.push` and skip the `arrOfAdds` collection completely. (note that the closure is not yet bound to this btw! so best use an arrow function or bind)

N.B.
If your example is from a react component, note that it is considered a bad practice to modify `this.state` directly, but `setState` should be used. But if your markers are an observable array, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Hey @mweststrate!  Thanks for answering.  I tried your suggestion initially and I was unable to get it to work because 'this' was undefined inside of the the geocode block -- do you know how to bypass this?

Comment: yes, use `function(results, status) {}.bind(this)`, or create a variable at the start of your function `var _this = this` and use `_this` in the callback. But make sure you understand what is going on here! It is very confusing for beginners, but very essential to understanding javascript: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/apC.md